# Parallel Resistors (special cases formula)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, power

> 1) A car's rear window defroster uses $n=15$ strips of resistive wire in a parallel arrangement. If the total resistance is 1.4 ohms, what is the resistance of one wire?

Solution: I rearranged the formula and got the following answer $$ R= nR_{T} = (15)(1.4 \Omega) = 21 \Omega .$$

> 2) **Question : What is the total power dissipated in the defroster if 12 V is applied to it?**

Relevant equations:

$$ R_{T} = \frac {R}{n} $$
$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} $$

The attempt at a solution:

To get the total power dissipated I assumed I would use the formula $$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} = \frac{12^2}{1.4 \Omega} = 102W $$

I was wrong though, the answer is 6.86 W in the answers section of the book.

$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} = \frac{12^2}{21 \Omega} = 6.86 W $$

What I'm guessing is they used the resistance value of one wire (21 ohms) for the resistance. My question is, ***why did they use the resistance of one wire and not the total resistance of the wires?*** Especially since they were asking for the total power dissipated?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is because the book got it wrong and you got it right!

Your working looks fine to me - nothing more to add.

Comment: Wow, that would be a first! I guess that's good news though. I see no errata for the book either. Thank you for your reply!